# Optional Bind Variables to match against same field

Tags: oracle, plsql, exadata

Barriers: I can't CREATE anything. No GTT's, PROCs, etc. I'm querying an Exadata data lake and whatever script I create will be executed from Toad or SQL Developer.  The platform is Oracle 11g.

I'm creating a self-serve report that relies on two types of parameters: Date Range and DNIS (essentially, a number identifying an IVR call flow).  There is at least one DNIS, potentially as many as three:

```
WHERE DNIS IN ('1234567', '9876543', '1232345')
```

I would like to create 3 bind variables: :DNIS1, :DNIS2, and :DNIS3 where one or more variables may be populated and if not, NULL.

In Theory:

```
WHERE DNIS IN (:DNIS1, :DNIS2, :DNIS3)
```

Perhaps a better question would be; given my limitations, how would one create a dynamic IN() clause? Is this possible?

Comment: What's wrong with `WHERE DNIS IN (:DNIS1, :DNIS2, :DNIS3)`? I can't understand what you need different from this.

Comment: Hard coded, the query returns a set within 30 seconds or so.  Running the query using this format runs without end.  I had to kill it manually after it ran for 7 minutes.

Comment: Please show an explain plan.

Comment: Is DNIS stored in the database as a number or a string?

Comment: OldP - I don't have rights to execute an explain plan.  APC - good question and sorry I didn't include it.  DNIS is VARCHAR2(50).

Comment: @mf.cummings have you tried adding `IN (TO_CHAR(:DNIS1), TO_CHAR(:DNIS2), TO_CHAR(:DNIS3))` and see, if the performance is any better.

Comment: @Sudipta - I tried as you suggested and received: ORA-00904: "T0_CHAR": invalid identifier

Comment: @mf.cummings  its `TO` and not `T0`

Comment: @Sudipta - In my defense, I hand't had my first cup of coffee in the morning!  Thank you, my friend.  This works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Sudipta Mondal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1013142/sudipta-mondal) (see comments) the answer was to wrap the bind variables in TO_CHAR()

```
WHERE DNIS IN (to_char(:DNIS1), to_char(:DNIS2), to_char(:DNIS3) )
```

Comment: So were `:DNIS1` etc declare as numbers?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson the field was of type VARCHAR2(50)

Comment: So the improvement was due to index suppression or something, rather than any actual datatype conversion? Just curious.